# pecl_http extension does not seem to load

Tags: php

PHP version: 5.5.15

**Installation steps**

To install `pecl_http` 2.5.0, I use:

```
pecl install pecl_http
```

To install `pecl_http` 1.7.6 I use:

```
gunzip http*.tgz
pecl install *.tar
```

**Shows in CLI, but not in browser**

They appear in `pecl list`:

```
pecl_http 2.5.0   stable                                                                         
propro    1.0.0   stable                                                                         
raphf     1.0.4   stable
```

```
php --info | grep -A100000 http | grep -B100000 http.etag.mode
```

```
http                                                                                             

HTTP Support => enabled                                                                          
Extension Version => 2.5.0                                                                       

Used Library => Compiled => Linked                                                               
libz => 1.2.3.4 => 1.2.3.4                                                                       
libcurl => 7.22.0 => 7.22.0                                                                      
libevent => 1.4 or greater => 1.4.14b-stable                                                     
libidn (IDNA2003) => 0.26 => unknown                                                             

Directive => Local Value => Master Value                                                         
http.etag.mode => crc32b => crc32b
```

**My php.ini**

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                         
; Dynamic Extensions ;                                                                         
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  

; ... skip a bunch of comments ...

extension=raphf.so                                                          
extension=propro.so                                                         
extension=http.so
```

I also did this for all the `php.ini`s found on my system. I used `config-set` for both `pear` and `pecl` to set the ini path. Upon reinstalling `pecl_http`, `pecl` recognized ini and set `extension="http.so"` but that did not work either.

**Browser `php_info()` is using the same ini as CLI**

```
php --info | grep php.ini

Loaded Configuration File => /ini/path/php.ini
```

Yet, I don't see the http extension in the browser with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` test page. `extension_loaded` doesn't return true either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of Linux are you running under?

Comment: Just to make sure: did you restart your webserver?